# How would you declare a two dimensional array of pointers in C?

Tags: c, arrays, multidimensional-array, function-pointers

...without using typedef.

My boss claims he was once asked this in an interview, and when he gave his answer the interviewers told him he couldn't use typedefs because it was poor style.

Regardless, he likes to throw the question out at people just to see if they can get it right , usually at new programmer lunches. No one ever gets it right (especially without a pen and paper or computer handy). I want to be ready next time he tries to stump someone with it >:D

Comment: So since when are typedefs bad style? I want to see the names of the people who were responsible for this idea on my desk by tomorrow.

Comment: avakar is ... simply right, I don't understand the point of this question. Perhaps it's been 10+ years since your boss actually programmed in C, and he faintly remember this as being difficult? Or is there some part of the "challenge" you've forgotten to include?

Comment: @DrJokepu: typedefs can't be forward-declared. That's not really an issue in C, typically, but it is in C++. It's bad for modularization.

Comment: I finally figured it out; he's asking for an array of pointer to an array of pointer to something: T *(*a[N])[M].  See my answer below for variations on the theme.

Comment: cdecl is your friend for questions like this.

Comment: I say: A read about one of the myriads of sites explaining how declarations are read is your friend for questions like this. Building complex declarations is easy. But that doesn't mean that typedefs are evil or that they are for wusses... They are useful for increasing readability, of course

Comment: Note that my "typedefs are for wusses" line was meant to be humorous.  Although I will say that typedefs can sometimes *cause* readability problems, particularly with pointer and function types.  Sometimes it's good to know that I'm dealing with a function pointer that takes 2 int arguments, rather than an opaque "callback" type.

Comment: @John Bode, yeah, i understand. That's why i loled :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
void* array[m][n];
```

Will give you a 2D array of void pointers. I'm not sure what's so confusing about this, unless I misunderstood your question.

Answer (score 11):

2D array of pointers to what?

```
T *p[N][M];     // N-element array of M-element array of pointer to T
T (*p[N][M])(); // N-element array of M-element array of pointer to 
                // function returning T
```

If we're talking about pointers to 2D arrays, then things only get slightly more interesting:

```
T a[N][M];            // N-element array of M-element array of T
T (*p)[M] = a;        // Pointer to M-element array of T
T (**p2)[M] = &p;     // Pointer to pointer to M-element array of T
T (*p3)[N][M] = &a;   // Pointer to N-element array of M-element 
                      // array of T
T (**p4)[N][M] = &p3; // Pointer to pointer to N-element array of 
                      // M-element array of T
```

Edit: wait, I think I may be getting what you're after.

```
T *(*a[N])[M];        // a is an N-element array of pointer to M-element
                      // array of pointer to T
```

Edit: Now we get really silly:

```
T *(*(*a)[N])[M];     // a is a pointer to an N-element array of 
                      // pointer to M-element array of pointer to T

T *(*(*(*f)())[N])[M];  // f is a pointer to a function returning
                        // a pointer to an N-element array of pointer
                        // to M-element array of pointer to T

T *(*(*f[N])())[M];     // f is an N-element array of pointer to 
                        // function returning pointer to M-element 
                        // array of pointer to T
```

And for the pathologically insane:

```
T *(*(*(*(*(*f)())[N])())[M])(); // f is a pointer to a function 
                                 // returning a pointer to a N-element
                                 // array of pointer to function 
                                 // returning M-element array of
                                 // pointer to function returning
                                 // pointer to T
```

Typedefs are for wusses.

Comment: "Typedefs are for wusses." LOOOOOL

Comment: Up voting this purely for the above quote.

Answer (score 2):

```
void*** p2DArray = (void***)malloc( numAxis1 * sizeof( void** ) );

int count = 0;
while( count < numAxis1 )
{
    p2DArray[count] = (void**)malloc( numAxis2 * sizeof( void* ) );
    count++;
}
```

And there ya go.  You can now access the array by going p2DArray[n][m] and get at the void* stored there.

Don't see why you'd need to use typedefs anyway ...

Edit: hahahaha or what avakar suggested ;)

Comment: In C, you should never cast the return of malloc().

Comment: @unwind: You should never cast the return of malloc? So you can't allocate anything else than void*, which is useless in itself?

Comment: Nah char* pChar = malloc( 1 ); is valid code if i recall correctly.  I don't seem to remember there being any harm in casting the return of malloc ... but I do use C++ more than C.

Comment: The harm is that if you forget to include the definition of malloc(), the cast will hide your error.  Since it serves no real purpose...

Comment: void pointers are implicitly converted to other object pointer types without the need for a cast.   

    T *x = malloc(sizeof *x * num_elements);

is idiomatic C.  Prior to C89 malloc() returned char*, so a cast was necessary, but not that many of us are working on 20+ year old implementations.

Answer (score 0):

Row major in C/C++, column major in Matlab/Fortran and for some unknown reason C#/native interop with multidimensional arrays.

```
int x = 4;
int y = 4;
void** data = malloc(x * y * sizeof(void*));
```

Answer (score 0):

The thing about typedefs and function pointers is that it easifies the mental strain of programmers.

I guess the problem comes from there, using void pointers would solve this, though you'd have to cast the FP whenever you're using it to get rid of all warnings.